# can't configure laravel homestead well

Tags: php, laravel

I configured the virtual machine, but when i put the url in the browser, keeps showing a page that says "it works". And nothing change.

this is my configuration (homestead.yml)

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: /Users/nvFede/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - /Users/nvFede/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/nvFede/code/testapp
      to: /home/vagrant/code/testapp

sites:
    - map: testapp.app
      to: /home/vagrant/code/testapp/public

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Comment: What url are you using to access it? Also does it have the correct port?

Comment: I put the same url in the written in the file. testapp.app/

Comment: try `testapp.app:8000` then ;-)

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 0):

The Homestead vm will only accept requests on port 8000.

Browse to:

```
http://testapp.app:8000
```